# Set SelectBox value through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox with multiple Options in it. I have an onchange handler on the selectbox which fires a different action depending on the selected option. This works well.

The first entry has the value 'empty' and no display text, so when the page loads, the first empty entry is selected so any other entry can be selected and used with onchange.

What i want to do is reset the selection to the empty entry everytime an action was called. I was thinking, that couldn't be so hard :-)

I tried the following:

```
//setting the value of the selectbox
document.getElementById('gadgetChooser').value='empty';

//setting selectIndex
document.getElementById('gadgetChooser').selectedIndex = 0;

//setting selectIndex
document.getElementById('gadgetChooser').options[0].selected = true;
```

None of the above mentioned ways have an effect on the actual view of the selectbox. The only thing that changes by setting the value is the value itsself that will be submitted, but the selectbox entry is not reset.

any suggestions?

Comment: Setting the selected index should work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/JfRSQ/ please add more details... how you create the drop down? What is that "action" you're doing? You have any other code after this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/BprVD/1/

**Edit:**

As requested by Chris, here's the complete solution http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/YjBWc/2/ c/o Shadow Wizard and myself.

Comment: That gets close but what i mean is this: http://jsfiddle.net/YjBWc/1/ btw: great link!

Comment: Okay, sorry, a bit confused. So you really need to use the getElementById() method?

Comment: @Chris here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/YjBWc/2/ you used the `getElementById` in the wrong way.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - Haha, I was going to do the same thing, but I wanted to know if that's what he was really looking for.

Comment: @Stellaire it doesn't really matter, it's two ways to achieve the same result of getting the element. What matters is how to set selected item, and your way is correct. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, the fiddle i posted was not right. In the question i wrote how i tried it. I used single brackets like this `('gadgetChooser').selectedIndex` as in the fiddle of Shadow Wizard i'm now using `("gadgetChooser").selectedIndex` and it works. Is there a difference between this notations? Thank you for your help! Would you please update your answer with this solution, so anyone else reading this question can see the solution a bit easier?